# Unable to login with iOS app that incorporates MobileSDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I have a question about the Mobile SDK for iOS.

We are implementing IP restriction settings in a sandbox environment,
I have set up IP restrictions in the sandbox environment so that test devices can communicate with the AP to which they connect.
At this time, the login is normal on the Salesforce app.

However, on the Sandbox login screen, where the SalesforceSDK is installed in the app, the login always fails even if the same ID and password are used to log in.

```
AuthHelper.loginIfRequired
```

I have added bootconfig.plist, but is there any other additional configuration that I need to do?

---

Device log.

```
Login Time (JST) Access Source IP Type Status Browser Platform Application Client Version API Type API Version Login URL TLS Protocol TLS Cipher Suite HTTP Method Authentication Method Reference Login Sub Type   
4/27 11:43 210.156.*. * Remote Access Client Restricted IP Unknown WebKit Mobile iPhone Browser N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Unknown Hybrid Application OAuth User-Agent 
4/27 11:42 210.156.*. * Remote Access Client Restricted IP Unknown WebKit Mobile iPhone Browser N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Unknown Hybrid Application OAuth User-Agent 
4/27 11:42 210.156.*. * Remote Access Client Restricted IP Unknown WebKit Mobile iPhone Browser N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Unknown Hybrid Application OAuth User-Agent 
4/27 11:41 210.156.*. * Remote Access Client Restricted IP Unknown WebKit Mobile iPhone Browser N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Unknown Hybrid Application OAuth User-Agent 
4/27 11:27 210.156.*. * Remote Access Client Restricted IP Unknown WebKit Mobile iPhone Browser N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Unknown Hybrid Application OAuth User-Agent 
4/27 11:26 210.156.*. * Remote Access Client Restricted IP Unknown WebKit Mobile iPhone Browser N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Unknown Hybrid Application OAuth User-Agent 
4/26 13:30 1.73.*. * Remote Access 2.0 Success Salesforce 242 iPhone Salesforce for iOS N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 unknown Hybrid application OAuth user-agent for 
4/26 13:30 1.73.*. * Remote access client Success Salesforce 242 iPhone browser N/A N/A N/A N/A test.salesforce.com TLS 1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 unknown Hybrid application OAuth user-agent Agent

4/27 Error logs
4/26 Logs with successful logins are logged in directly from the Saleforce app.
```